# Problem display images in ListView with infinity pagination

Tags: flutter, dart

Problem with displaying images in ListView, have error that 'CachedNetworkImage' is nota subtype of type 'String'

Basicly want to fetch images from this firebase colection and display them in 'ListView' with pagination

```
initSliderImages() async {
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('galerytab1');
    result.snapshots().listen((data) {
      List imgs = [];
      data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        var imageData = change.doc.data();
        String image = imageData?['url'];
        imgs.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: image));
      });

      setState(() {
        images = imgs;
      });
    });
  }
```

```
class CategoryTab1 extends StatefulWidget {
  final String category;
  CategoryTab1({Key? key, required this.category}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CategoryTab1State createState() => _CategoryTab1State();
}

class _CategoryTab1State extends State<CategoryTab1> {
  List images = [];

  late ScrollController controller;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // addUrls();
    controller = ScrollController()..addListener(_scrollListener);
    initSliderImages();
    if (this.mounted) {
      context.read<CategoryTab1Bloc>().data.isNotEmpty
          ? print('data already loaded')
          : context.read<CategoryTab1Bloc>().getData(mounted, widget.category);
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.removeListener(_scrollListener);
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _scrollListener() {
    print(controller.position.extentAfter);
    if (controller.position.extentAfter < 13) {
      setState(() {
        images.addAll(List.generate(2, (index) => 'Inserted $index'));
      });
    }
  }

  // //
  // void addUrls() {
  //   final List<String> imgs = List.generate(
  //     16,
  //         (_) {
  //       int random = Random().nextInt(16) + 16; // 250-500
  //       return
  //         // initSliderImages();
  //         // 'https://picsum.photos/$random/$random';
  //           'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/klosterkatz-c914e.appspot.com/o/galerytab1%2F1.png?alt=media&token=5b0e9c74-ec5a-42ca-aa59-309f41938a28';
  //
  //
  //
  //
  //     },
  //   );

  //   setState(() {
  //     images.addAll(imgs);
  //   });
  // }
  //

  // Fetch images from databse for list

  initSliderImages() async {
    var result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('galerytab1');
    result.snapshots().listen((data) {
      List imgs = [];
      data.docChanges.forEach((change) {
        var imageData = change.doc.data();
        String image = imageData?['url'];
        imgs.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: image));
      });

      setState(() {
        images = imgs;
      });
    });
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('imagesimageimagesimagesimageismageimage');
    print('$images');
    print(images.length);

    return NotificationListener<ScrollNotification>(
      onNotification: (ScrollNotification notification) {
        if (notification.metrics.pixels ==
            notification.metrics.maxScrollExtent) {
  initSliderImages();
          // addUrls();
        }

        return true;
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        key: widget.key,
        itemCount: images.length,
        itemExtent: 250,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Image.network(
            images[index],
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            key: ValueKey(images[index]),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add `CachedNetworkImage` in a list of String !

You have to map each url of your `images` list into a `CachedNetworkImage` like this :

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return CachedNetworkImage(
        imageUrl: images[index],
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
        key: ValueKey(images[index]),
      );
    }
```

You should also rename your `images` variable into `urls` or `imageUrls`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this widget is not in usage in code, will edit question..

Comment: The problem still the same ! You can't add CachedImageNetwork, which is a Widget, in a list of String.
I will edit my answer according to your edit

Comment: For some reason still have error that CachedNetworkImage is not a subtype of 'String'

Comment: Replace the line `imgs.add(CachedNetworkImage(imageUrl: image));` with `imgs.add(image);`

Comment: Yessss.. Perfecttt noww workk.  Thank You so much! I try to fix this maybe 1 week :D

Comment: One more question, i gues that the image now not load with pagination or leazyload, when i open this page 1-2 time fast app crash

Comment: Try to fix it yourself and if you don't success, post a new question :)

Comment: I try but for some reason crash everytime i load screen and scroll faster

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250063/discussion-between-comaxd-ea1-and-f-perroch).